# Interpret assumption of residuals for choosing better model

Tags: python

I have 3 plots with fitted values against error terms: model 1 with 1 dependent variable, model 2 with 3 dependent variables, and model 3 with 7 dependent variables.
But how should I make assumptions and describe which model is better based on these plots?
They all share a similar pattern, except the variance of residuals becomes smaller.

[image: plot1]
[image: plot2]
[image: plot]

But how should I make assumptions and describe which model is better based on these plots?
They all share a similar pattern, except the variance of residuals becomes smaller.